# Getting KeyError although the key is in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dict_example={('EUR', 'IDR'): None, ('EUR', 'BGN'): None, ('EUR', 'CHF'): None, ('EUR', 'USD'): None, ('IDR', 'EUR'): None, ('IDR', 'BGN'): None, ('IDR', 'CHF'): None, ('IDR', 'USD'): None, ('BGN', 'EUR'): None, ('BGN', 'IDR'): None, ('BGN', 'CHF'): None, ('BGN', 'USD'): None, ('CHF', 'EUR'): None, ('CHF', 'IDR'): None, ('CHF', 'BGN'): None, ('CHF', 'USD'): None, ('USD', 'EUR'): None, ('USD', 'IDR'): None, ('USD', 'BGN'): None, ('USD', 'CHF'): None} 

for i in dict_example.keys():
   print(i)
   a='(\'{}\', \'{}\')'.format(i[1], i[0])
   print(dict_example[a])
```

This code is just so you understand my problem. I have another goal (when there is currency pair in key, to check if its opposite is also in the dict. For example ('EUR', 'USD'), check if ('USD', 'EUR') is present in the dict).

Why do i get the `KeyError`: '('IDR', 'EUR')'  even if it's in the dictionary ?

Thanks !

Comment: The keys are **tuples**.  But you're trying to use a **string** that _looks like_ a tuple.  Use this instead `a = (i[1], i[0])`

Comment: You need to show us *exact* code, Meriole.  `dict_example` is not defined in the snippet and you don't show how you're coding that key lookup.  We only have what you share to go by.  So make sure to provide a *minimal*, *reproducible* example with your next question.

Comment: Thanks you both. 
But the solution from John Gordon has worked. I'm not so expert, so it's a subtility i didn't master.

Comment: In fact, since `i` is looping over the keys list, `i` is **already** the exact key.  You can just use `dict_example[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
dict_example={('EUR', 'IDR'): None, ('EUR', 'BGN'): None, ('EUR', 'CHF'): None, ('EUR', 'USD'): None, ('IDR', 'EUR'): None, ('IDR', 'BGN'): None, ('IDR', 'CHF'): None, ('IDR', 'USD'): None, ('BGN', 'EUR'): None, ('BGN', 'IDR'): None, ('BGN', 'CHF'): None, ('BGN', 'USD'): None, ('CHF', 'EUR'): None, ('CHF', 'IDR'): None, ('CHF', 'BGN'): None, ('CHF', 'USD'): None, ('USD', 'EUR'): None, ('USD', 'IDR'): None, ('USD', 'BGN'): None, ('USD', 'CHF'): None} 

for i in dict_example.keys():
   print(i)
   a=(i[1], i[0])
   print(dict_example[a])
```

Comment: dict_example not defined in your code

Comment: Worked like this, yes thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like:

```
my_dict = {
    ('EUR', 'IDR'), ('IDR', 'EUR')
}

opposite_pairs = set()

for pair in my_dict:
    opposite_pair = (pair[1], pair[0])
    if opposite_pair in my_dict:
        opposite_pairs.add(pair)

if opposite_pairs:
    print("Yep, the opposite pair is also in the dict")
    for pair in opposite_pairs:
        print(pair)
else:
    print("Nope opposite pairs not found.")
```

Comment: `my_dict` in your code is a set, not a dict.